# Log4j filter by package

Tags: log4j

I would like to have log4j (v1.2.17) send ...

... to **fileAppender**

- INFO (and above) from all packages

... to **console**

- if from "*my.project*" then INFO (and above)
- else WARN (and above) for all other packages

How can I do this?  I'd prefer a properties file if possible, but would switch to XML if necessary.

I've tried combinations of loggers, non-additivity, Threshold, & LevelMatchFilter but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can definitely be done. Below you will find some example code and log4j properties that will do what you want.

Here is the first example class:

```
package my;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Example1 {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Example1.class);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        logger.debug("debug from my.Example1 - should display nowhere!");
        logger.info("info from my.Example1 - should display in log file only!");
        logger.warn("warning from my.Example1 - should display in console and log file!");
        logger.error("error from my.Example1 - should display in console and log file!");
        logger.fatal("fatal from my.Example1 - should display in console and log file!");
    }
}
```

Here is the second example class:

```
package my.project;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Example2 {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Example2.class);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        logger.debug("debug from my.project.Example2 - should display nowhere!");
        logger.info("info from my.project.Example2 - should display in console and log file!");
        logger.warn("warning from my.project.Example2 - should display in console and log file!");
        logger.error("error from my.project.Example2 - should display in console and log file!");
        logger.fatal("fatal from my.project.Example2 - should display in console and log file!");
    }
}
```

Here is the log4j.properties file:

```
# The root logger will accept INFO messages or higher and send them to the log file
# and to a console appender that filters out any messages below WARN level
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, R, warnStdout

# Configure a console appender that will be used for messages of any level
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

#This will be used to print WARN level or higher messages to console 
log4j.appender.warnStdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.warnStdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.warnStdout.Threshold=WARN

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.warnStdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=test.log

log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
# Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1

log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n

# Classes in the my.project package will accept messages of INFO level or higher
# and send those messages to the console and to the log file
log4j.logger.my.project=INFO, stdout, R
# Need to set additivity to false or else both the my.project and root loggers 
# will accept messages from classes in package my.project
log4j.additivity.my.project=false
```

Here is the console output after running Example1 followed immediately by Example2:

```
 WARN [main] (Example1.java:11) - warning from my.Example1 - should display in console and log file!
ERROR [main] (Example1.java:12) - error from my.Example1 - should display in console and log file!
FATAL [main] (Example1.java:13) - fatal from my.Example1 - should display in console and log file!
 INFO [main] (Example2.java:11) - info from my.project.Example2 - should display in console and log file!
 WARN [main] (Example2.java:12) - warning from my.project.Example2 - should display in console and log file!
ERROR [main] (Example2.java:13) - error from my.project.Example2 - should display in console and log file!
FATAL [main] (Example2.java:14) - fatal from my.project.Example2 - should display in console and log file!
```

Here is the test.log file content after running Example1 followed by Example2:

```
INFO main my.Example1 - info from my.Example1 - should display in log file only!
WARN main my.Example1 - warning from my.Example1 - should display in console and log file!
ERROR main my.Example1 - error from my.Example1 - should display in console and log file!
FATAL main my.Example1 - fatal from my.Example1 - should display in console and log file!
INFO main my.project.Example2 - info from my.project.Example2 - should display in console and log file!
WARN main my.project.Example2 - warning from my.project.Example2 - should display in console and log file!
ERROR main my.project.Example2 - error from my.project.Example2 - should display in console and log file!
FATAL main my.project.Example2 - fatal from my.project.Example2 - should display in console and log file!
```